# Images problems in WP when I import the website on my local web server, why?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, migration

I am pretty new in WP (I came from Joomla) and I have the following problem trying to import an old WP blog (made using WP 3.5) on my local web server.

I have put the old blog foder into my **www** Apache directory and then I have imported the database on my local MySql DB.

After, I went into the **wp_options** DB table and I have change the value of the **option_value** field related to the rows **home** and **siteurl** putting in them the correct address (on my localhost web server)

Ok, it's seem to work fine: I can see my website and the articles on it but now I have the following problem:

If an article contains an image, I can't see this image and if I open it in the browser, I get the the following error message: **404 Not Found**

```
Not Found

The requested URL "/it/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Andrea-Alfieri-chef-bassa3.jpg" was not found on this server.
```

And in the browser address bar I have the following **wrong URL**:

```
http://www.myOldWebSite.it/it/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Andrea-Alfieri-chef-bassa3.jpg
```

It is wrong because it is related to the old website URL and not to my localhost website.

I think that must be some wrong settings on my database and that I have to change it but I don't know what I have to change

Can you help me? Some ideas?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Three things to try. change `settings->permalinks` to `default` - you can change it back later.

also in `settings->general` there is a fields called `Wordpress Address` and `Site Url`

then open your db.sql file in a text editor like sublime text or notepad++ and do a search and replace of the old url to the new local url. Then re-import the edited db.sql file into the the database on the new host.

This has worked for me in the past when moving WP from one host to another.

Answer (score 0):

In database in table of posts (example: wp_posts ) guid is the url of specific image
you can update this table :

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://localhost');
```

I hope to help

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know what your doing in terms of migrating your blog. 
I would assume that if you went in to the settings->general section, both the URL's will match the new URL of the local server. Judging by what you have mentioned in the question.

Providing when you access the blog and then access the Dashboard the URL remains that of the local server then ,most likley everything is as it should be.

Another thing you can try which I have done before to resolve issue when migrating is to use the Wordpress search and replace plugin. This simply checks all tables for any instances of the old URL and replces this with the new one.

Make sure to backup the database before using this tool. Here is the URL for the plugin.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Hopefully this will be of some use to you.